# Add menu to CMS page

Tags: menus

I am absolutely new to wordpress & woocommerce 
my question is how to use/call menu in CMS page
eg- I created a menu my-menu & I want this menu in my CMS page

can anyone help with how to call menu in CMS page

Answer (score 1):

Try below code ( with proper modifications if needed ) in your `'header.php'`

```
<?php
       if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation')) :
          wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'menu_class' => 'nav']);
       endif;
    ?>
```

For more details try [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) link

Comment: I need to call menu in CMS page , not in template/php files

Comment: What you mean by "CMS page"?

Comment: any page we create with dashboard

Answer (score 1):

This is not very usual and should be done through templating, but to answer your question:

1. Create the menu you want in your page and put it into a widget.
2. Use any widget shortcode plugin (as example: "[amr shortcode any widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/)") to insert the shortcode for that widget to insert it in your page.

Please view the documentation of the plugin of your choice for further information on how to use the shortcode.

Inserting a menu into a single pages content is not really common, so there is no "out of the box" way to do it without templating or using a plugin.